# Message Id based receive ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am trying to use JMS Message Selector with ActiveMQ. I read the documentation on Apache's site. But I am not able to get where to specify the selection condition while creating the Consumer.

e.g.:

```
MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(dest);
```

To set selection on this consumer, what should I code? It will be great if anyone can provide a snippet or link to a tutorial explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`javax.jms.Session`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/Session.html) API makes this quite plain:

```java
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(dest, "message selector");
```

It's just one line below the `session.createConsumer(dest)` variant. Perhaps you grew weary too soon?